# How to convert an mkv (with subtitles) to something Nexus One friendly?

Tags: ffmpeg, nexus-one, mplayer, subtitle, mkv

I have this ffmpeg one-liner that's been good for generating video files for my Nexus One:

```
ffmpeg -i infile.mkv -acodec aac -s 572x238 -vcodec libx264 -vpre ipod640 -ab 128k -b 512k -f mp4 -strict experimental outfile.mp4
```

But it does this ignorant of the subtitles in `infile.mkv` -- usually not a problem, unless I'm dealing with a non-english movie.  In cases like this, I'd like to use the Japanese audio track, and the English subtitles.

The funny bit is that I can use `mplayer` to play it using `-alang` and `-slang`, but don't know how to use `mencoder` to make Nexus One friendly videos.  I can use `ffmpeg` to generate Nexus One friendly videos, but can't figure out how to get it to use a specific subtitle track.

If someone can solve one of these for me, I'll be a happy camper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after a lot of googling and trial & error, here is what worked for me:

```
mencoder infile.mkv -o outfile.mp4 -vf dsize=512:352:2,scale=-8:-8,harddup -oac faac -faacopts mpeg=4:object=2:raw:br=128 -of lavf -lavfopts format=mp4 -ovc x264 -sws 9 -x264encopts nocabac:level_idc=30:bframes=0:bitrate=264:threads=auto:global_header:threads=auto:subq=5:frameref=6:partitions=all:trellis=1:chroma_me:me=umh
```

It's not using ffmpeg, but it appears to be working.